# Connecting to hazelcast mancenter fails

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to connect hazelcast man center grammatically in java but I am getting "Failed to send response"

```
INFO: [192.168.203.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast 
Management Center on address: 
http://localhost:8080/mancenter
Jan 03, 2018 5:27:56 PM 
com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [192.168.203.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Initializing cluster partition table 
arrangement...
Jan 03, 2018 5:27:59 PM 
com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService
**WARNING: [192.168.203.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Failed to send response, 
responseCode:500 url:http://localhost:8080/mancenter/collector.do**
```

This is how I am connecting to java program

```
public class HazelcastMember {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");
    //ConsoleApp.main(args);

    Config cfg = new Config();
    cfg.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true).setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter");
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
}
```

}

I am running the environment using Java 1.8, hazelcast-spark 0.2 and spark 2.2.1

Comment: How do you start Management Center? Is it on the same machine? Do you start it on port 8080 or use another port?

Comment: I start the mancenter by there script flle startManCenter.bat provided in their mancenter download. Yes it is on same machine and running on 8080 port.

Comment: What is the ManCenter version?

Comment: @gokhan-oner it is 3.9.1

Comment: You need to use ManCenter 3.7, since your cluster version is 3.7

Answer (score 6):

You need to use same minor versions of Hazelcast & Management Center. Logs you shared say member version is 3.7, so you need to use ManCenter 3.7.x as well.

Comment: My problem was that I had 2 hz libraries, one in the pom.xml and another cached.
Thanks.